# Reconciling notation for forwards algorithm

Tags: pr.probability, hidden-markov-models

I am studying the forwards algorithm for hidden Markov models via [Rabiner's tutorial paper](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/ece417/fa2017/rabiner89.pdf) and Kevin Murphy's *"Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective"*.

In Rabiner's paper, he introduces the variable

$$
\alpha_t(i) = p(\mathbf{x}_{1:t}, z_t=i).
$$

That is, the joint probability of the sequence of observations and hidden state $i$ at time $t$.

In Murphy's section on the forwards algorithm, he introduces the forwards variable as

$$
\alpha_t(j) = p(z_t=j|\mathbf{x}_{1:t}).
$$

I am having a difficult time understanding how these two could be equal, unless Murphy is simply deviating from the standard notation of the forwards variable.

I further confused myself when I evaluated the recursive step $\alpha_{t+1}(j)$ as described in Rabiner:

$$
\alpha_{t+1}(j) = \Big[\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_t(i)p(z_{t+1}=j|z_t=i)\Big]p(x_{1:t+1}|z_{t+1}=j).
$$

If I plug in the original definition of $\alpha_t$ here, I get

\begin{align*}
\alpha_{t+1}(j) &= \Big[\sum_{i=1}^Np(\mathbf{x}_{1:t}, z_t=i)p(z_{t+1}=j|z_t=i)\Big]p(\mathbf{x}_{1:t+1}|z_{t+1}=j)\\
&= p(\mathbf{x}_{1:t})p(z_{t+1})p(\mathbf{x}_{1:t}|z_{t+1}=j).
\end{align*}

At this point, I am unable to reconcile how

$$
p(\mathbf{x}_{1:t+1}, z_{t+1}=i) = p(\mathbf{x}_{1:t})p(z_{t+1})p(\mathbf{x}_{1:t}|z_{t+1}=j).
$$

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.